# npm install cypress@9.5.4 --save-dev fails and instead install version 11.2.0

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, cypress, npm-install

## Solution for this thread!

After installing cypress don't validate the version via the command `npx cypress verify` for some reason each time we do this it imposes the latest version over the specific want we installed, this is what we did and it worked! Hope this helps the community

## Details about the problem

1. We do require install Cypress `version 9.5.4`
2. Despite the fact we are following the Cypress documentation its installed version 11.2.0
3. This is a fresh installation, therefore there isn't a cache of previous versions interfering.
4. Package.Json shows that the version and its dependencies are `version 9.5.4`
5. The sequence of commands we performed is described in the section **Steps**

## Steps followed for installing Cypress specific version

*This command installs Node.js*:

`c: & cd \strains\node & msiexec /i node.msi /qb /l* Node.js-Install.log`

*Then we proceed to check the npm and node versions installed, to confirm installation went through*:

`npm -v; node -v`

*Now we proceed to install cypress now the dependencies were validated*:

`If(-NOT (Test-Path C:\Cypress)){mkdir C:\Cypress}; cd C:\Cypress npm init npm install cypress@9.5.4 --save-dev`

*Now to validate if cypress installed and which version*:

`npx cypress open It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 11.2.0`

Then I did decide to clean all the cypress cache and even so I got this message `Deleted all binary caches except for the 11.2.0 binary cache.`

To my surprise cypress output version shown above is from `version 11.2.0`, contradictory to this the `package.json` shows that the only version present in that file is `9.5.4` as shown in the snippet below.
To make easier the search from below snippet do a `Ctrl+F` and type `"cypress": { "version": "",` it would be present only one version of cypress that as mentioned before is `9.5.4` with all its related dependencies (that are a lot)
So, were am i failling? why version `11.2.0` is the one installed? will appreciated all your help

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "@colors/colors": {
      "version": "1.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@colors/colors/-/colors-1.5.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ooWCrlZP11i8GImSjTHYHLkvFDP48nS4+204nGb1RiX/WXYHmJA2III9/e2DWVabCESdW7hBAEzHRqUn9OUVvQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "optional": true
    },
    "@cypress/request": {
      "version": "2.88.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@cypress/request/-/request-2.88.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Zp7F+R93N0yZyG34GutyTNr+okam7s/Fzc1+i3kcqOP8vk6OuajuE9qZJ6Rs+10/1JFtXFYMdyarnU1rZuJesg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "aws-sign2": "~0.7.0",
        "aws4": "^1.8.0",
        "caseless": "~0.12.0",
        "combined-stream": "~1.0.6",
        "extend": "~3.0.2",
        "forever-agent": "~0.6.1",
        "form-data": "~2.3.2",
        "http-signature": "~1.3.6",
        "is-typedarray": "~1.0.0",
        "isstream": "~0.1.2",
        "json-stringify-safe": "~5.0.1",
        "mime-types": "~2.1.19",
        "performance-now": "^2.1.0",
        "qs": "~6.5.2",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
        "tough-cookie": "~2.5.0",
        "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
      }
    },
    "@cypress/xvfb": {
      "version": "1.2.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@cypress/xvfb/-/xvfb-1.2.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-skbBzPggOVYCbnGgV+0dmBdW/s77ZkAOXIC1knS8NagwDjBrNC1LuXtQJeiN6l+m7lzmHtaoUw/ctJKdqkG57Q==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "debug": "^3.1.0",
        "lodash.once": "^4.1.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "debug": {
          "version": "3.2.7",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-3.2.7.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-CFjzYYAi4ThfiQvizrFQevTTXHtnCqWfe7x1AhgEscTz6ZbLbfoLRLPugTQyBth6f8ZERVUSyWHFD/7Wu4t1XQ==",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "ms": "^2.1.1"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    },
    "cypress": {
      "version": "9.5.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cypress/-/cypress-9.5.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-6AyJAD8phe7IMvOL4oBsI9puRNOWxZjl8z1lgixJMcgJ85JJmyKeP6uqNA0dI1z14lmJ7Qklf2MOgP/xdAqJ/Q==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@cypress/request": "^2.88.10",
        "@cypress/xvfb": "^1.2.4",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
        "@types/sinonjs__fake-timers": "8.1.1",
        "@types/sizzle": "^2.3.2",
        "arch": "^2.2.0",
        "blob-util": "^2.0.2",
        "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
        "buffer": "^5.6.0",
        "cachedir": "^2.3.0",
        "chalk": "^4.1.0",
        "check-more-types": "^2.24.0",
        "cli-cursor": "^3.1.0",
        "cli-table3": "~0.6.1",
        "commander": "^5.1.0",
        "common-tags": "^1.8.0",
        "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
        "debug": "^4.3.2",
        "enquirer": "^2.3.6",
        "eventemitter2": "^6.4.3",
        "execa": "4.1.0",
        "executable": "^4.1.1",
        "extract-zip": "2.0.1",
        "figures": "^3.2.0",
        "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
        "getos": "^3.2.1",
        "is-ci": "^3.0.0",
        "is-installed-globally": "~0.4.0",
        "lazy-ass": "^1.6.0",
        "listr2": "^3.8.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "log-symbols": "^4.0.0",
        "minimist": "^1.2.6",
        "ospath": "^1.2.2",
        "pretty-bytes": "^5.6.0",
        "proxy-from-env": "1.0.0",
        "request-progress": "^3.0.0",
        "semver": "^7.3.2",
        "supports-color": "^8.1.1",
        "tmp": "~0.2.1",
        "untildify": "^4.0.0",
        "yauzl": "^2.10.0"
      }
    },
    "pretty-bytes": {
      "version": "5.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pretty-bytes/-/pretty-bytes-5.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-FFw039TmrBqFK8ma/7OL3sDz/VytdtJr044/QUJtH0wK9lb9jLq9tJyIxUwtQJHwar2BqtiA4iCWSwo9JLkzFg==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "proxy-from-env": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-from-env/-/proxy-from-env-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-F2JHgJQ1iqwnHDcQjVBsq3n/uoaFL+iPW/eAeL7kVxy/2RrWaN4WroKjjvbsoRtv0ftelNyC01bjRhn/bhcf4A==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "psl": {
      "version": "1.9.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/psl/-/psl-1.9.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-E/ZsdU4HLs/68gYzgGTkMicWTLPdAftJLfJFlLUAAKZGkStNU72sZjT66SnMDVOfOWY/YAoiD7Jxa9iHvngcag==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "pump": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pump/-/pump-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-LwZy+p3SFs1Pytd/jYct4wpv49HiYCqd9Rlc5ZVdk0V+8Yzv6jR5Blk3TRmPL1ft69TxP0IMZGJ+WPFU2BFhww==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "end-of-stream": "^1.1.0",
        "once": "^1.3.1"
      }
    },
    "punycode": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-2.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XRsRjdf+j5ml+y/6GKHPZbrF/8p2Yga0JPtdqTIY2Xe5ohJPD9saDJJLPvp9+NSBprVvevdXZybnj2cv8OEd0A==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "qs": {
      "version": "6.5.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-6.5.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-qxXIEh4pCGfHICj1mAJQ2/2XVZkjCDTcEgfoSQxc/fYivUZxTkk7L3bDBJSoNrEzXI17oUO5Dp07ktqE5KzczA==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "request-progress": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress/-/request-progress-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-MnWzEHHaxHO2iWiQuHrUPBi/1WeBf5PkxQqNyNvLl9VAYSdXkP8tQ3pBSeCPD+yw0v0Aq1zosWLz0BdeXpWwZg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "throttleit": "^1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "restore-cursor": {
      "version": "3.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/restore-cursor/-/restore-cursor-3.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-l+sSefzHpj5qimhFSE5a8nufZYAM3sBSVMAPtYkmC+4EH2anSGaEMXSD0izRQbu9nfyQ9y5JrVmp7E8oZrUjvA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "onetime": "^5.1.0",
        "signal-exit": "^3.0.2"
      }
    },
    "rfdc": {
      "version": "1.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rfdc/-/rfdc-1.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-V2hovdzFbOi77/WajaSMXk2OLm+xNIeQdMMuB7icj7bk6zi2F8GGAxigcnDFpJHbNyNcgyJDiP+8nOrY5cZGrA==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "rimraf": {
      "version": "3.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-3.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-JZkJMZkAGFFPP2YqXZXPbMlMBgsxzE8ILs4lMIX/2o0L9UBw9O/Y3o6wFw/i9YLapcUJWwqbi3kdxIPdC62TIA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "glob": "^7.1.3"
      }
    },
    "rxjs": {
      "version": "7.5.7",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-7.5.7.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-z9MzKh/UcOqB3i20H6rtrlaE/CgjLOvheWK/9ILrbhROGTweAi1BaFsTT9FbwZi5Trr1qNRs+MXkhmR06awzQA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "tslib": "^2.1.0"
      }
    },
    "safe-buffer": {
      "version": "5.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer/-/safe-buffer-5.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-rp3So07KcdmmKbGvgaNxQSJr7bGVSVk5S9Eq1F+ppbRo70+YeaDxkw5Dd8NPN+GD6bjnYm2VuPuCXmpuYvmCXQ==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "safer-buffer": {
      "version": "2.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safer-buffer/-/safer-buffer-2.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YZo3K82SD7Riyi0E1EQPojLz7kpepnSQI9IyPbHHg1XXXevb5dJI7tpyN2ADxGcQbHG7vcyRHk0cbwqcQriUtg==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "semver": {
      "version": "7.3.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-7.3.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-NB1ctGL5rlHrPJtFDVIVzTyQylMLu9N9VICA6HSFJo8MCGVTMW6gfpicwKmmK/dAjTOrqu5l63JJOpDSrAis3A==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "lru-cache": "^6.0.0"
      }
    },
    "shebang-command": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/shebang-command/-/shebang-command-2.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-kHxr2zZpYtdmrN1qDjrrX/Z1rR1kG8Dx+gkpK1G4eXmvXswmcE1hTWBWYUzlraYw1/yZp6YuDY77YtvbN0dmDA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "shebang-regex": "^3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "shebang-regex": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/shebang-regex/-/shebang-regex-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7++dFhtcx3353uBaq8DDR4NuxBetBzC7ZQOhmTQInHEd6bSrXdiEyzCvG07Z44UYdLShWUyXt5M/yhz8ekcb1A==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "signal-exit": {
      "version": "3.0.7",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/signal-exit/-/signal-exit-3.0.7.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-wnD2ZE+l+SPC/uoS0vXeE9L1+0wuaMqKlfz9AMUo38JsyLSBWSFcHR1Rri62LZc12vLr1gb3jl7iwQhgwpAbGQ==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "slice-ansi": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/slice-ansi/-/slice-ansi-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-pSyv7bSTC7ig9Dcgbw9AuRNUb5k5V6oDudjZoMBSr13qpLBG7tB+zgCkARjq7xIUgdz5P1Qe8u+rSGdouOOIyQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "ansi-styles": "^4.0.0",
        "astral-regex": "^2.0.0",
        "is-fullwidth-code-point": "^3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "sshpk": {
      "version": "1.17.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sshpk/-/sshpk-1.17.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-/9HIEs1ZXGhSPE8X6Ccm7Nam1z8KcoCqPdI7ecm1N33EzAetWahvQWVqLZtaZQ+IDKX4IyA2o0gBzqIMkAagHQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "asn1": "~0.2.3",
        "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
        "bcrypt-pbkdf": "^1.0.0",
        "dashdash": "^1.12.0",
        "ecc-jsbn": "~0.1.1",
        "getpass": "^0.1.1",
        "jsbn": "~0.1.0",
        "safer-buffer": "^2.0.2",
        "tweetnacl": "~0.14.0"
      }
    },
    "string-width": {
      "version": "4.2.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width/-/string-width-4.2.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-wKyQRQpjJ0sIp62ErSZdGsjMJWsap5oRNihHhu6G7JVO/9jIB6UyevL+tXuOqrng8j/cxKTWyWUwvSTriiZz/g==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "emoji-regex": "^8.0.0",
        "is-fullwidth-code-point": "^3.0.0",
        "strip-ansi": "^6.0.1"
      }
    },
    "strip-ansi": {
      "version": "6.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-6.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Y38VPSHcqkFrCpFnQ9vuSXmquuv5oXOKpGeT6aGrr3o3Gc9AlVa6JBfUSOCnbxGGZF+/0ooI7KrPuUSztUdU5A==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "ansi-regex": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },
    "strip-final-newline": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-final-newline/-/strip-final-newline-2.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-BrpvfNAE3dcvq7ll3xVumzjKjZQ5tI1sEUIKr3Uoks0XUl45St3FlatVqef9prk4jRDzhW6WZg+3bk93y6pLjA==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "supports-color": {
      "version": "8.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-8.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-MpUEN2OodtUzxvKQl72cUF7RQ5EiHsGvSsVG0ia9c5RbWGL2CI4C7EpPS8UTBIplnlzZiNuV56w+FuNxy3ty2Q==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "has-flag": "^4.0.0"
      }
    },
    "throttleit": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/throttleit/-/throttleit-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-rkTVqu6IjfQ/6+uNuuc3sZek4CEYxTJom3IktzgdSxcZqdARuebbA/f4QmAxMQIxqq9ZLEUkSYqvuk1I6VKq4g==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "through": {
      "version": "2.3.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/through/-/through-2.3.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-w89qg7PI8wAdvX60bMDP+bFoD5Dvhm9oLheFp5O4a2QF0cSBGsBX4qZmadPMvVqlLJBBci+WqGGOAPvcDeNSVg==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "tmp": {
      "version": "0.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp/-/tmp-0.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-76SUhtfqR2Ijn+xllcI5P1oyannHNHByD80W1q447gU3mp9G9PSpGdWmjUOHRDPiHYacIk66W7ubDTuPF3BEtQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "rimraf": "^3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "tough-cookie": {
      "version": "2.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie/-/tough-cookie-2.5.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-nlLsUzgm1kfLXSXfRZMc1KLAugd4hqJHDTvc2hDIwS3mZAfMEuMbc03SujMF+GEcpaX/qboeycw6iO8JwVv2+g==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "psl": "^1.1.28",
        "punycode": "^2.1.1"
      }
    },
    "tslib": {
      "version": "2.4.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-2.4.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-tGyy4dAjRIEwI7BzsB0lynWgOpfqjUdq91XXAlIWD2OwKBH7oCl/GZG/HT4BOHrTlPMOASlMQ7veyTqpmRcrNA==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "tunnel-agent": {
      "version": "0.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent/-/tunnel-agent-0.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-McnNiV1l8RYeY8tBgEpuodCC1mLUdbSN+CYBL7kJsJNInOP8UjDDEwdk6Mw60vdLLrr5NHKZhMAOSrR2NZuQ+w==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "safe-buffer": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },
    "tweetnacl": {
      "version": "0.14.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl/-/tweetnacl-0.14.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KXXFFdAbFXY4geFIwoyNK+f5Z1b7swfXABfL7HXCmoIWMKU3dmS26672A4EeQtDzLKy7SXmfBu51JolvEKwtGA==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "type-fest": {
      "version": "0.21.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/type-fest/-/type-fest-0.21.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-t0rzBq87m3fVcduHDUFhKmyyX+9eo6WQjZvf51Ea/M0Q7+T374Jp1aUiyUl0GKxp8M/OETVHSDvmkyPgvX+X2w==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "universalify": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/universalify/-/universalify-2.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hAZsKq7Yy11Zu1DE0OzWjw7nnLZmJZYTDZZyEFHZdUhV8FkH5MCfoU1XMaxXovpyW5nq5scPqq0ZDP9Zyl04oQ==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "untildify": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/untildify/-/untildify-4.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KK8xQ1mkzZeg9inewmFVDNkg3l5LUhoq9kN6iWYB/CC9YMG8HA+c1Q8HwDe6dEX7kErrEVNVBO3fWsVq5iDgtw==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "uuid": {
      "version": "8.3.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid/-/uuid-8.3.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+NYs2QeMWy+GWFOEm9xnn6HCDp0l7QBD7ml8zLUmJ+93Q5NF0NocErnwkTkXVFNiX3/fpC6afS8Dhb/gz7R7eg==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "verror": {
      "version": "1.10.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/verror/-/verror-1.10.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZZKSmDAEFOijERBLkmYfJ+vmk3w+7hOLYDNkRCuRuMJGEmqYNCNLyBBFwWKVMhfwaEF3WOd0Zlw86U/WC/+nYw==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
        "core-util-is": "1.0.2",
        "extsprintf": "^1.2.0"
      }
    },
    "which": {
      "version": "2.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/which/-/which-2.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-BLI3Tl1TW3Pvl70l3yq3Y64i+awpwXqsGBYWkkqMtnbXgrMD+yj7rhW0kuEDxzJaYXGjEW5ogapKNMEKNMjibA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "isexe": "^2.0.0"
      }
    },
    "wrap-ansi": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/wrap-ansi/-/wrap-ansi-7.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YVGIj2kamLSTxw6NsZjoBxfSwsn0ycdesmc4p+Q21c5zPuZ1pl+NfxVdxPtdHvmNVOQ6XSYG4AUtyt/Fi7D16Q==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "ansi-styles": "^4.0.0",
        "string-width": "^4.1.0",
        "strip-ansi": "^6.0.0"
      }
    },
    "wrappy": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/wrappy/-/wrappy-1.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-l4Sp/DRseor9wL6EvV2+TuQn63dMkPjZ/sp9XkghTEbV9KlPS1xUsZ3u7/IQO4wxtcFB4bgpQPRcR3QCvezPcQ==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "yallist": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist/-/yallist-4.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-3wdGidZyq5PB084XLES5TpOSRA3wjXAlIWMhum2kRcv/41Sn2emQ0dycQW4uZXLejwKvg6EsvbdlVL+FYEct7A==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "yauzl": {
      "version": "2.10.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/yauzl/-/yauzl-2.10.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-p4a9I6X6nu6IhoGmBqAcbJy1mlC4j27vEPZX9F4L4/vZT3Lyq1VkFHw/V/PUcB9Buo+DG3iHkT0x3Qya58zc3g==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "buffer-crc32": "~0.2.3",
        "fd-slicer": "~1.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **Solution for this thread!** after installing cypress don't validate the *version* via the command `npx cypress verify` for some reason each time we do this it impose the latest version over the specific want we installed, this is what we did and it worked! Hope this helps the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution for this thread!

Use the next command to install the specific version you do require, please remember to ***replace*** the ***version*** with the your own version after the **@9.5.4**

```
If(-NOT (Test-Path C:\Cypress)){mkdir C:\Cypress}; cd C:\Cypress npm init npm install cypress@9.5.4 --save-dev
```

After installing cypress don't validate the version via the command `npx cypress verify` for some reason each time we execute this command after finishing the installation it overrides the specific version we installed **9.5.4** with the latest version available at the moment in time you're performing the installation, E.G, **11.2.0** or whatever is the latest version at that moment in time.

Take in consideration that our server is **Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Edition** therefore it might vary your experience slightly due the difference in OS version(s) 2008, 2008-r2, 2012 and so forth, This what we did and it worked!